# D3.js not recognizing floats from CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to produce a two line graph with D3.js.

However, when trying to draw the svg line, my console complains the following:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL120.01533182…".
```

This seems to be the second svg line, where all the y-coordinates are NaN. Why is this so?

I figured, that I might be converting my csv wrong, but console.log -says that my y-coordinates are indeed numbers.

```
// Get the data
d3.csv("debt.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.year = parseDate(d.year);
    d.debt = +d.debt;
    d.debtgdp = parseFloat(d.debtgdp); // Trying to parse to a float
    console.log(typeof d.debtgdp); // Recognizes that it is a number
});
```

CSV looks like this:

```
year,debt,debtgdp 
1940,29,39.7
1950,228,24.8
1960,271,10.11
1970,707,9.2
1980,3022,9.0
1990,9593,10.5
1995,60121,61.0
2000,63435,46.6
2001,61760,42.8
2002,59253,40.0
```

All of the code can be found here: http://niklasstrengell.fi/temp/juha/

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you try the unary operator, just like `+d.debt`?

Comment: You might consider editing your post to include sample data of "debt.csv".

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes, I did! However, it isn't working. :/

Comment: @zett42 good idea, did that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is very difficult to find out if you just *look* at the code: a space just after `debtgdp` and before the newline, at the first row of your CSV file.

The hint was this: with or without both `parseFloat()` and the unary operator, `d.debtgdp` is always `undefined`.

The solution was simply removing that space. Check for spaces and non printable characters in your CSV from now on.

Here is your working code: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/a4763e5cc824039cff369f6679d4722b

Comment: Haha, awesome! Thanks for the effort. Would not have noticed that. This was truly a good exercise, not only in programming, but in carefulness too. :)